# Paint select from edge

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-paint

Using Microsoft Paint, with the Select tool, when I move within
the image the cursor changes to allow a selection:

> [image: example 1]

If I want to select from the edge, I move past the edge and drag inward.
However I have noticed if you move past the edge, you are no longer able
to make a selection:

> [image: example 2]

It seems the only way to select from the edge is to carefully move the
cursor to the last pixel and start from that point. This can be difficult
to move precisely down to the pixel. Is a better way available to do
this?

Comment: I have found that the only way to really ensure that you capture the edge while using Paint is to start your selection within the picture, and then move out towards the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I wrote my own Go program for cropping:

```go
crop-image [flags] <file>
  -bottom int
        pixels
  -left int
        pixels
  -right int
        pixels
  -top int
        pixels
```

https://github.com/89z/sienna/tree/master/cmd/crop-image

Answer (score 0):

Can be a solution to move a little bit the edge around your image, so you will be able to select the pixel you want!

[image].